# how to set up a simple postgres connection to wundergraph?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set up a simple connection to my postgres database server using a brand new wundergraph install. I went through the tutorials, but it does not say what to do after I configure the wundergraph.config.ts file, so forgive the naive question.

I added these lines to my "wundergraph.config.ts" file.

```
const myDB = introspect.postgresql({
  apiNamespace: "db",
  databaseURL:
    "postgres://username:password@database-server.com:5432/database_name",
});

configureWunderGraphApplication({
  apis: [myDB],
});
```

Questions:

1. How do I know what the results of connecting to the database were? I assume it somehow didn't go through because nothing is coming up in .wundergraph/schemas and nothing is showing up in the logs.
2. How do I know what tables are available in the database? So I can know wundergraph properly introspected them.